# How many leaves will be contained in a full binary tree of height 5?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

According to my class definition, a full binary tree is a tree where:

- Every leaf node has the same depth
- Every non-leaf node has two children

This is confusing me (the first part in particular) because this sounds like a perfect binary tree. I have read multiple definitions of a full binary tree on the internet and I don't see the "Every leaf node has the same depth" part. I have came across a question I have to answer: How many leaves will be contained in a full binary tree of height 5?

I think this answer is a range of numbers between 11 and the perfect binary tree of height 5 (63). But the question seems like there is only one answer, and going by my class definition, the answer would be just 63? To me the definition of full binary tree is ambiguous and it is confusing me. Am I missing something?

Comment: You're right - it seems that the question confuses a "full binary tree" with a "perfect binary tree". That said, either way the answer can't be 11.

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your confirmation.